# SceneKit: error, inconsistency in lru list

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, scenekit

I am developing a game on the SceneKit using Swift. And sometimes I am getting this error.

More frequently it's happen when I unload scene (SCNScene) and open level selection screen (simple collectionViewController on UIKit)

[3149:1029348] SceneKit: error, inconsistency in lru list

whole debug console are filled with it, and my app is freeze and not respond on any actions, sometimes even need to reboot device.

Comment: this is an internal error regarding memory management. How to unload the scene?

Comment: I think I have found solution, and it is about unloading old scene, so before restart level i do self.scene = nil and then self.scene = SCNScene(), and it is ok no error appears, but if miss self.scene = nil, then errors are happening all the time